# phpmyadmin website buttons etc not working

Tags: google-app-engine, phpmyadmin

I've deployed phpmyadmin to a google app engine service. First i had a login problem:

> Failed to set session cookie. Maybe you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS to access phpMyAdmin.

I've changed this setting:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

from cookie to http and now I am able to log in.

Only problem is none of the tabs, buttons, links etc are working, except when i open them in a seperate tab. I've tried using different browsers and clearing history etc but the problem remains.

I think this might have something to do with the fact that i'm hosting it on google app engine standard enviroment but looking at the logs there i get no errors.

I've also tried adding

```
$cfg['Profiling'] = false;
```

But that doesnt seem to do anything.

Tried changing config.inc.php to include:

```
$cfg['Profiling'] = false;
```

Changed this setting:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'http';
```

From 'cookie' to 'http'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin setup on Google App engine is discussed here: https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/16922#issuecomment-974499976